# Jquery add input array fields not passed to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have simple form with jquery adding unlimited input fields in my form. Problem is that when jquery adds a field, it dose not actually post any value on submit. Any ideas how to debug this? Here is my code:

```
<script  src="../orders/src/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var addDiv = $('#addinput');
        var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

        $('#addNew').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="item[]" value="" placeholder="Input here" /><a href="#" id="remNew">Премахни</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
        });

        $('#remNew').live('click', function() {
            if( i > 2 ) {
                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                i--;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<form action="add-exe.php" method="post">
      <div id="addinput">
        <p>
           <a href="#" id="addNew">Add line</a>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Запази">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the simple php side wich is trying to read what's added into the array. So far added fields via Jquery aren't passed

```
$itemlist = count($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : array();
print_r(array_values($itemlist));
```

If the input fields are not added dynamically - form is posting the array just fine

Comment: `live` is deprecated, use `on` instead

Comment: @FezVrasta the name has [] which means an array totally acceptable by PHP

Comment: I am able to get values of item which is appended to div.

Comment: @Noob can u show the code on add-exe.php and show us how you are trying to get the values

Comment: You need to give each input a different ID (or don't give them any ID, since it's probably not needed). Duplicate IDs are not allowed, it might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *on* instead of *live*. Also the code which adds listeners for removing fields should be called after every addition:

```
var addDiv = $('#addinput');
var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;

$('#addNew').on('click', function() {
    $('<p><input type="text" id="p_new" size="40" name="item[]" value="" placeholder="Input here" /><a href="#" class="remNew">Премахни</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
    i++;
    assignRemoveEvents();
});

var assignRemoveEvents = function() {
    $('.remNew').off('click').on('click', function() {
        if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });
}
```

Once this is done you should get the data into PHP. If you post the code of your php we may find out what is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the fast feedback. I dont know why I did started with on usage insted of live but didnt worked for me, just no inputs get added without error.

My php side is just trying to read the array


$itemlist = count($_POST['item']) ? $_POST['item'] : array();
print_r(array_values($itemlist));

Sorry first time here idk how to make that php look like a code :/

Comment: It's not necessary to call `live` after each addition. `live` performs delegation, so it works with dynamically added elements. It should be replaced with `on`, but you have to use the delegation syntax, not the binding syntax. And in either case, it has nothing to do with which fields get sent to PHP.

Comment: @Saranya Sadhasivam you are saying that above code is working just fine for you?